# Capture the current browser url in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I want to take current url in asp.net page. I want to bind this in repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server">   
    <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlOtherUrl" runat="server" Text="link" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink></p>           
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

For example - http://www.test.com?ID=3
How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current page url by doing this:

```
Response.Write(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

in your case i guess you need it here:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This page has a very concise guide:
http://powerasp.net/content/new/get-current-page-url.asp